# Change innerhtml of anchor within a class

Tags: javascript, class, innerhtml

---

Hi,

I have a question about changing the HTML within an anchor that sits within a DIV with a particular class. i.e."

```
<div class="class-name">
   <a href="#">Link Text Here</a>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I am unable to give the link it's own class or DIV (working on a pre-coded platform) therefore looking at reaching it through a div and replacing the "Link Text Here" with "ABC".

Many thanks,
Brenden

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` may be of interest to you:

```
document.querySelector(".class-name>a").innerHTML = "...";
```